# Cloud Monthly Pricing Calculator

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, azure, cloud

Amazon did a great job by providing an online calculator for AWS; resides here:
http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

Which really helps to find your way among a swarm of cloud options.

Is there similar a tool for GAE (Google App Engine) or Microsoft Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft will have a calculator and other tools around PDC. 
newdesic has a tool that you can use - http://azureroi.cloudapp.net/

Comment: Just to get back on this one. Microsoft has, since quite some time, a cool looking pricing calculator available: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=full.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware of. Of course, lacking tiered pricing, calculating costs for App Engine is very straightforward - just multiply expected usage by cost-per-unit for each of the 5 dimensions.

Comment: We are investigating cloud solutions and the problem is there are so much diversion in both definition of a cloud based system and it's implementation. My 1st guess is it is not proper for our problem (for example I need to listen on a port for incoming data 24/7), yet I am in charge to find out if cloud could solve any of our problems (up-time, distributed data centers, ...). So far I think cloud is not mature enough to be used in real world and I am studying private cloud solutions (implementing our system in Erlang maybe? or using VMWare or Xen?). Honestly I am a bit lost and out of focus!

Comment: You can't use App Engine to 'listen on a port' - only for HTTP and XMPP requests. Amazon's EC2 may suit your needs, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is an unofficial [billing calculator for Google App Engine](http://g-calculator.appspot.com/advanced.html).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this diagnostic tool which seems good for making an estimation: 
http://www.whitestratus.com/cloud-platform-diagnostic-tool